# Form resetting through Code

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have developed a Report on the Form. User has manually dragged the fields on the user Interface of the Form for the present situation and his convenience.

When he is running the report again the previous modifications done by him are showing in the form where the fields are disarranged. He want to see this in previous State like I actually designed it.

How can I reset the form in exact status through code every time I run the Form?

Comment: "the previous modifications done by him are showing in the form", do you mean "in the report"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the following property to prevent the user from modifying the layout of your form;

```
AllowUserSetup
```

To remove the users current changes you must remove the usage data for this form - If you wish to allow them to change form layout but want it to reset every time it runs you may wish to do this via code (not recommended);

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2011/04/21/users-don-t-want-to-delete-their-usage-data-but-you-ve-redeveloped-the-form-the-solution.aspx